# ES6 Angular 1.6 LokiJS module injection filename error

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, lokijs

My probleme is :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function Loki(filename, options) due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: filename
```

I use Agular 1.6 withe lokiJs for angular.
The code is formated in ES6 with webpack.

notice I commented all references to Loki in my controller.
Only injection is used in.

```
export default class loginController{
    constructor($scope, Loki, $mdDialog, $timeout, $location, $cookies){
        console.log('foo');
        if($cookies.get('user')){
            $location.path('/programmes');
        }

        this.user = {
            login:'plop',
            pwd:undefined
        }
        var db_name = 'app.db';
        //var db = new Loki('${db_name}');
        var profiles;
/*
        db.loadDatabase({},function(){
            return profiles = db.getCollection('profiles') || db.addCollection('profiles');
        });
*/
        console.log('ttoot');
       this.ui = {
           'shake' :false,
           'register': false,
       };
   }
```

for the controller and my app.js :

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
import ngMessage from 'angular-messages';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import ngCookies from 'angular-cookies';
import lokijs from 'lokijs';

/*import './../dependencies/loki/lokijs.js';
import loki from './../dependencies/loki/loki-angular.js';
*/

import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import appLogin from './components/login/login.module.js';
import appProg from './components/programmes/prog.module.js';
import appSeance from './components/seances/seances.module.js';

import router from './configs/routing.js';
import run from './run/run.js';


angular.module('app', [
    ngMaterial,
    ngAnimate,
    ngMessage,
    ngRoute,
    ngCookies,
    appLogin,
    appProg,
    appSeance,
    lokijs,
    uirouter,
])
.config(router)
.run(run)
;
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: I think is not utils :)

Comment: as I think u having problem with lokijs module loading. Check for the same. Try to import angular-loki as well

Comment: Is lokijs  ! "Try to import angular-loki as well" You mean ?

Comment: yes as I saw the module directory lokijs module has been defined in loki-angular.js so try for that if that works or not

Comment: I make the test: app work without lokijs

Comment: need help !  no move since ...